# Is there a limit for this expression?

Tags: calculus, limits, convergence-divergence

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{\cos(n) + \sin(n)+1}{n^{\frac54}}$$

I am unable to determine whether or not the limit of the expression exists.

Can someone give me a hint ?

Comment: But the equals sign does not belong here.

Comment: Absolutely right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint** $|\cos(n)+\sin(n)+1|\le |\cos(n)|+|\sin(n)|+1 \le 3$

Answer (score 2):

Whenever we have limits of fractions that involves numerators of a sinusoidal nature 
(i.e. $\sin$ and $\cos$), the Sandwich / Squeeze Theorem is usually the go-to method.

Now we know $$\bigg|\frac{\cos{(n)}+\sin{(n)}+ 1}{n^\frac{5}{4}}\bigg| \leq\frac{1+1+1}{n^\frac{5}{4}} = \frac{3}{n^\frac{5}{4}}$$
Thus we have \begin{align}-\frac{3}{n^\frac{5}{4}} \leq \frac{\cos{(n)}+\sin{(n)}+ 1}{n^\frac{5}{4}} \leq\frac{3}{n^\frac{5}{4}}\end{align}
As $n\to \infty$, we have that both the LHS and RHS of our inequality tends to $0$.

Thus we have $$\displaystyle \lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{\cos{(n)}+\sin{(n)}+1}{n^\frac{5}{4}}=0$$

Comment: Sandwich rules !

Comment: Haha! Indeed - always a nice method to use :)

Answer (score 1):

The numerator is bounded (why?) The denominator tends to infinity, because the exponent is >1

Comment: so the limit is 0 in this case?

Comment: The latter half of this answer is perhaps a bit misleading; in general, $\lim_{n\to \infty} n^{p} = \infty$ if and only if $p>0$.

Comment: True that. In this case, exponent>0 is indeed sufficient. My bad.

Answer (score 1):

The numerator sin(n) + cos(n) + 1 = sqrt(2)*sin(n + pi/4) + 1, which is no more than 1 + sqrt(2) by all means.

While the denominator tends to positive infinity, then you can use comparison principle.